# How to send multiple parameters on fetch get request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am using Fetch for GET request, but need to send multiple parameters for filter function.
I have `depSeq`, `workName` parameters, but have no idea how to send them via Fetch.
I used axios before, and I could send params as second parameter, so it was kinda straight forward to send params.
But on Fetch method, I don't see anyone using params like axios does.

How can I send multiple params on Fetch GET method?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_json_data

Comment: where is your code ?

Answer (score 1):

It is either you hard code it in the url you are using like so:

```js
let url = 'https://example.com/path/?depSeq=true&workName=true';
```

Or you use the URL constructor to construct a new URL for that endpoint so that you can now change the search property of the endpoint like so:

```
let url = new URL('/path', 'https://example.com');
url.search = new URLSearchParams({depSeq: true, workName: true});
```

I will advise you to use the second approach because that way you can easily change search parameters on the fly for a given endpoint and it allows code reuse.

Comment: you should use single quote instead of backticks.

Comment: @Raptor those appear to be smart quotes, not back ticks, probably some intermediate text editor changing them. I just fixed them.

Comment: Yea @ZacAnger my mobile keyboard. I’ll edit to double quotes just to be safe.

Comment: @Drizzle you're welcome. It's a pain on any platform, not just mobile. I always have to remember to turn that off when I set up a new laptop.